# High latency when using key on kafka message in spark structured sreaming

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured Streaming v3.0.1, and I am experiencing the following issue: When sending a message to Kafka without a key (i.e., key=null), the application runs without any latency issues. Each micro-batch, which consists of approximately 1.5 million records, takes about 1 minute to process. However, when I add a key column as the Kafka key, the processing time increases to more than 3 minutes per micro-batch.

In both cases, the value is converted to Avro format using 'abris.avro.functions.to_avro'.

Without key:

```
df
.writeStream
.format("kafka")
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation())
...
.select(to_avro(allColumns, toAvroConfig).as('value))
```

With kafka key:

```
df
.writeStream
.format("kafka")
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation())
...
.select(col("objKey").as("key"), to_avro(allColumns, toAvroConfig).as('value))
```

Please assist me.

Tried to read the same column and name it differently, and then had no latency issues.

Comment: What difference do you see in the Spark UI for the stages?

Comment: In Spark UI - didn't notice any differences. From my investigation we found that the latency was caused due to high 'kafka.linger.ms' - which was set to 1000ms, and we suspect that using a keys instead of nulls, on a topic with hundreds of partitions created high latency, cause kafka was waiting at least one second to batch.size to be filled

Comment: Choosing a bad Kafka partition key could result in hotspot issues which might cause high latencies. Based on your use case, you’ll have to understand if you have chosen the right partition key or if you need a partition key at all. This article might help - https://newrelic.com/blog/best-practices/effective-strategies-kafka-topic-partitioning